# Hide a tag at certain screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, css

I want to hide following code at 1024 X 768 or lower screen resolutions:

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ankitnagpal"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

How do I do it? Please share some code or references. The users with low resolutions usually use Win XP. So please see if the solution is compatible with IE version of Win XP.

Which technology can do it? Javascript, CSS or jQuery?

Comment: see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: @karaxuna Is CSS3 (CSS media queries) compatible with IE version of Win XP?

Comment: You can also use Media-query of CSS3 of jQuery

Comment: @Ankit it's compatible with IE version >= 9.0 . See full browser compatibility information in link I provided at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually media queries does not work in internet explorer less than 9. If you want to manipulate only this element i recommend to use jQuery way

```
if ( $(window).width() <= 1024 && $(window).height() <= 768 )
  $('.addthis_toolbox').hide();
```

Actually it does not do something special. Of course, you can use

`$(window).on('resize', function(){ ... });`

If you want to do something else magic with your code, but what i understood, you do not need. 
If you have more elements to modify at certain resolution, i recommend to use css media queries and for compatibility with "awesome" IE you maybe will use [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $(window).width() for width AND
  $(window).height() for height 

 var your_width  = 1024;
 if($(window).width() > your_width)
  {
        //don't show
  }else{
       //show
  }
```

Comment: Is it compatible with IE version of Win XP?

Comment: Yes, i have mac but i just checked it on IE, it worked, let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
screen.height;
screen.width;
```

Based on that values you can calculate your margin to whatever suits you.
`$(window).width() & $(window).height()` gives the width and height of brrowser window not the resolution

[Example here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_screen_all)

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries!

Wrap your code in a container:

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ankitnagpal"></script>
    <!-- AddThis Button END -->
</div>
```

Css:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
   .container { display: none }
}
```

Comment: Media queries are not read by IE8 and lower and also you do not need a container, you already have the .addthis_toolbox wrapper